# What programs convert German audio to text (Ubuntu 18.04)?

Tags: 18.04, text, convert, audio-recording, german

Is there any tool in Ubuntu 18.04 I can use to convert German audio to text? I searched a lot but all applications use English.

Comment: not an answer, but the other way around for text to voice is gspeakers at http://gspeakers.sourceforge.net/  ( currently offline for me)

Comment: a search came up with this one     https://simon-listens.blogspot.com/2012/12/simon-040.html   ...  has source code.... BUT running the build.sh gave an error ,   "ERROR: Could not find KDE4 kde4-config",, I tried for 30 min and gave up. simon was last developed in 2012...